# How to temporarily hide elements while designing in Gluon Scene Builder?

Tags: scenebuilder

I have complex design that has several layers on top of each other. Problem is that if I click on object, other object that on top of it gets selected. How I can switch off visibility of my top objects while working on my bottom layer, so that they won't get in the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found how to achieve what I wanted. Just select element that in the way and in properties remove tick from visible. Now you can design without anything obstructing your view! Just don't forget to make visible all elements before you save your work. [image]